# MongoDb - Can you use $bitsAllSet in an aggregate projection or group?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a field stored in a mongo collection that is an integer bitmask, and I frequently use the [`$bitsAllSet`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/bitsAllSet/#-bitsallset) query operator to find documents where certain bit flags are set.

Now I would like to do an aggregation to get counts of documents for each bit flag. I figured I would start by trying to project if the bit is set or not.

Something like..

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate(
[
    { $project: { 
        bit1: { $bitsAllSet: ["$myBitMask", 1] },
        bit2: { $bitsAllSet: ["$myBitMask", 2] },
        bit3: { $bitsAllSet: ["$myBitMask", 4] },
        bit4: { $bitsAllSet: ["$myBitMask", 8] }
    } }
])
```

but this is invalid syntax and I cannot find anything in the mongo documentation that looks like it would help me accomplish this.

Is there a way achieve this?